# How to access XAMPP server from a seperate computer?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have been unsuccessful in connecting to my XAMPP server from a remote pc. I have checked my httpd-xampp.conf file and there is no LocationMatch section to input the "Allow from All". Not sure if this part just doesn't exist with newer versions of XAMPP, or if it is located in a different file?

Comment: Do you get a 403 or connection refused?

Comment: @osnapitzkindle I've changed in the .conf file; Listen localhost:80 and it seems to be connecting now. The issue that persists, is that when accessing my wordpress site, the site is not loading properly. Also, phpmyadmin is still giving me a 403 error

Comment: phpmyadmin can't be reached outside "localhost" by default because of the "new XAMPP policy", there's a file, I don't remember if it's an external file or it's in the main file, but you can remove this policy. Wordpress that doesn't load properly is because of some coding problems in it probably.

Answer (score 0):

Check on log file for more details about get 403, is first step to start investigate if problem is dir/file permission or httpd.conf misconfiguration